# Line break when entering a Space while editing a post

Tags: discussion, bug, edits

This situation will potentially be hard to recreate, but there is a question on Arqade that when editing changes spaces (<kbd>Space</kbd>) into hard enters/line breaks (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

It happens when editing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395275/rec-room-people-automatic-repawn-in-own-flag-game) on Arqade. When editing other questions it does not happen. Another user corroborated the occurrence (if necessary, I can share my soft- and hardware specifications, but since someone else was able to reproduce it, I think it is a server-based (?) bug (?)).

It only happens when editing anything after the two first lines (the first being an elliptic comment, the second an empty line).

Does anyone know why or how this happens? Is it a certain (string of) character(s) that might be responsible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saving the revision source (downloadable [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/6e0d335c-9ed3-476c-a3ba-4d4b06e8e283/view-source)) and opening it in a text editor immediately identifies the problem:

> ```
> I&nbsp;created&nbsp;a&nbsp;typical&nbsp;game&nbsp;captures&nbsp;the&nbsp;flag&nbsp;but&nbsp;I&nbsp;have&nbsp;a&nbsp;strange&nbsp;bug.&nbsp;If&nbsp;I&nbsp;am&nbsp;the&nbsp;1st&nbsp;player&nbsp;to&nbsp;enter&nbsp;the&nbsp;game&nbsp;(me=player&nbsp;id1)&nbsp;the&nbsp;game&nbsp;works&nbsp;well&nbsp;all&nbsp;players&nbsp;can&nbsp;respawn.&nbsp;But&nbsp;if&nbsp;another&nbsp;player&nbsp;comes&nbsp;before&nbsp;me&nbsp;and&nbsp;I&nbsp;have&nbsp;id=2,&nbsp;then&nbsp;the&nbsp;other&nbsp;player&nbsp;dies&nbsp;and&nbsp;stays&nbsp;in&nbsp;respawn(0sec)&nbsp;all&nbsp;the&nbsp;time.
> ```

The entire post has been written using non-breaking spaces (spaces which will not result in the line splitting and wrapping). As a result, whenever you add a *real* space, that space is a new place for the post to wrap correctly.

You can fix this by simply copying the entire contents of the post, and re-pasting it. That should replace all non-breaking spaces with normal spaces.

You can see the result of editing the spaces to normal ones in the markdown view of an edit:

[image: Image showing side-by-side markdown view of revision to the post in question. All spaces in the post are marked as having been removed and re-added as they were replaced with a different type of space.]

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks! I thought it might have been something like that, but couldn't switch the editor view, and figured these spaces would be removed automatically when posting something (for some reason).

Comment: @Joachim Yeah, the issue was pretty clear, proving it was less easy because every time I copied the text into a character checker all the spaces got fixed. Ended up having to open the revision history (`/posts/<id>/revisions`) to get the source link to download it.